# android - WebView disappears in Lollipop

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have an application that opens a web view to do a payment through internet banking, now the problem is every time I tab a text field or a button in that web view, the web itself turns blank completely.

This issue only happens in Lollipop and works fine for below Kitkat. Here is how I build my WebView:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setAnimationCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
webView.setFocusable(true);
webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
webView.setClickable(true);
```

EDIT: Correction, the webview disappears every time a keyboard appears not when I tab a button or text field

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658416/keyboard-covers-edittext-and-webview-in-lollipop-only) and related  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658416/keyboard-covers-edittext-and-webview-in-lollipop-only)