# Android Soft Keyboard covering WebView content

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to use a WebView in my Activity to display a standard login page, however it seems that the keyboard always covers the bottom half of the page (and it doesn't allow you to 'scroll' the part that isn't covered, like you'd expect).

Looking up the issue, I've tried the usual

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

However that doesn't seem to work. (I've tried adjustPan too)

[Now I found this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658416/keyboard-covers-edittext-and-webview-in-lollipop-only), but I have seen apps in Lollipop scroll the webview around like you'd expect to happen.

Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Edit: Also, my activity is not using the fullscreen flag.

Here is my Activity's XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview_login"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check "fitsSystemWindows" property

Comment: @IITAmiya Hmm, that didn't seem to have any effect. The only view that I have that on in my Activity is the toolbar, even after removing that, the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can overwrite the method named onSizeChanged() as following:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    if (onSizeChangedListener != null) {
        onSizeChangedListener.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }
}
```